# Magento 2 - Product sorting issue on category page using product attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, sorting, category-page

I made product attribute and assign it on of attribute set so that it will show in the admin product detail page. Based on this product attribute I sort the product collection on category page.

The problem is, I set the `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` to `Text field`. I will have to set the numeric value against each product in order to sort the product collection based on this attribute. It works fine from 1-9 but when I increase the count more than 9 like 10, 11 etc it destroy the sorting. It may be because field type is not number type

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: I have same issue, I have dropdown in attribute. Did you find any solution ? If yes can you please share?

Answer (score 4):

Please try following way using custom plugin, so please add plugin code in your custom extension as below

**/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="vendormodule_catalog_block_product_listproduct_toolbar" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Catalog/Block/Product/ProductList/Toolbar.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList;

class Toolbar
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry)
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection $collection
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $toolbar,
        $collection
    ){
        $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id')->order('{YOUR CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE CODE} ASC');
        $collection->getSize();

        return [$collection];
    }
}
```

Please try and let me know if you get any issue.

Comment: Bro I use the same for sorting. It works fine when I enter the value from `1-9` in my custom product attribute but when I increase the value from 9 like 10, 11. It will destroy the sorting like I said in my question. Anyways thanks for answering. For your effort. +1

Comment: So try with change in your database attribute type to int

Comment: During product attribute creation from admin, is there anyway to set product attribute type to `int`? There is nothing in `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner`  like number or etc